# SQL easiest way to filter out same rows?

Tags: sql

SQL noob here -- I'm trying to compare in one month, how many people changed their last names. My skills limit me, so the easiest way I can think of to do this is run 2 queries:

```
Query 1:
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM names_dataset
WHERE date='2013-05-27' 

Query 2:
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM names_dataset
WHERE date='2013-04-27'

Result query 1:
John        Smith
Michael     Johnson
James       Williams

Result query 2:
John        Smith
Michael     Johnson
James       Brown
```

The only result I want is "James Brown", which has the changed col2 on a different date.

I'm getting a lot of duplicate results from the two queries (ppl who didn't change names), how do I only filter out the rows where col2 changes?

Comment: How do you know if it's a legitimate name change?  Ie.  James Brown, James Jones, James Johnson, are those name changes, or just different people?  You need something unique to compare them on from day to day aside from first and last name.

Comment: Firstname is actually: 1582142475813, 2402291960465  and lastname is: 10000015249, 10527957.  I just simplified them to names for clarity's sake in this question

Comment: Can you add the full list of column names from names_dataset to your question?

Comment: Does firstname stay the same? is there anything unique?

Comment: firstname will always stay the same

Comment: @MarkBannister column names: date, firstname, lastname

firstname and lastname are all unique digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT t1.firstname,
           t1.lastname AS from_lastname,
           t2.lastname AS to_lastname
      FROM names_dataset AS t1
INNER JOIN names_dataset as t2
        ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname
     WHERE t1.date='2013-04-27' 
       AND t2.date='2013-05-27' 
       AND t1.lastname <> t2.lastname
```

This will provide a list of rows that had the same first name at both dates but different last names.

Comment: Yes. Additions and changes will be treated equal.

Comment: I think OP what wants is list of users with different value in column2 from 2 different dates, ie only changes not new rows

Comment: You are right. In that case it's somewhat more complicated. I'll try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your firstname field is unique this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT firstname, lastname
        FROM names_dataset
        WHERE date='2013-05-27'
     )day1
JOIN
     (SELECT firstname, lastname
        FROM names_dataset
        WHERE date='2013-04-27')
     )day2
ON day1.firstname = day2.firstname
WHERE day1.lastname <> day2.lastname
```

This returns everything, if you just want 'James Brown' then you'd change the select portion to:

```
SELECT day2.firstname, day2.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will find this approach helpful.  I use it to assign "ADDED" or "REMOVED" to each row that appears in one set but not the other:

```
select firstname, lastname,
       (case when MAX(which) = 'later' then 'ADDED'
             when MAX(which = 'earlier' then 'REMOVED'
             else '???'
        end)
from ((SELECT firstname, lastname, 'later' as which
       FROM names_dataset
       WHERE date='2013-05-27' 
      ) union all
      (select firstname, lastname, 'earlier'
       FROM names_dataset
       WHERE date='2013-04-27' 
      )
     ) t
group by firstname, lastname
having count(*) = 1;
```

It combines the names from the two groups and counts the number that appear once.  If the occurrence is in the later time period, then the record was added.  If in the earlier time period only, then it was removed.

Also, this is standard SQL, so it should work across most databases.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee4f5/23).

I used SQL Server for this; I would approach this with a self inner join (note the ID fields were just for test purposes).  Join the table to itself by first name and find where the first and last name fields don't match.  If you suspect a first name could have changed, invert this query for first names.

Final query:

```
SELECT *
FROM names n1
  INNER JOIN names n2 ON n1.FirstName = n2.FirstName
WHERE n1.LastName <> n2.LastName
```

Or, [my preferred method (SQL Fiddle also)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee4f5/22) would be to use an ID field and join with the ID field.  This would catch any changes in first or last name and is much simpler overall, plus it resolves the first comment, which rightly points out a problem - how do you know that James isn't a new person?  This query:

```
SELECT *
FROM names n1
  INNER JOIN names n2 ON n1.ID = n2.ID
WHERE n1.FirstName <> n2.FirstName
  OR n1.LastName <> n2.LastName
```